# Visual studio database project - Change database reference when deploying to dev/test/prod

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-devops

Is there a way to when building/deploying to different environments in azure devops.

For example in my sql project I have a reference to a database not in source control,
lets say i have a stored procedure that is selecting something from a table :
select * from [server3].[dbtest].dbo.testtable ...

Can I use something like an sqlcmd to set [dbtest] to $(database)?
And In the build/deploy step in devops change this to a different server?
Ie we have a dev sql server and a prod sql server....

I have tried to use the "add database reference" in  VS but that only seems to work if you have a .dacpac file.